# Testcafe Hover and jQuery :hover-selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I got an issue with TestCafé testing a megadropdown functionality.

In my test, i use the `.hover()` of TestCafé, which properly triggers the `mouseenter` event of my navigation link. In this `mouseenter`, i got the following if-clause with jquery (2.1.4):

```js
if ($(this).parent().find(':hover').length > 0) {
...
}
```

Now, when I trigger the hover through testCafe, this statement is never true, the length remains 0. 
I do see the `mouseenter`-event, I see the cursor drawn by TestCafé, but `jQuery(': hover').length` is always zero.

I don't know why this function was implemented like this and I don't want to change the code, I just wanted to run some automated test to check the functionality. Has anybody an idea of how a workaround/bugfix could look like?

*Update for reproducing properly*
https://jsbin.com/bivuzabala

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Hover issue`.page `https://jsbin.com/bivuzabala`;

test('Hover Test', async t => {
    const testroot = Selector('#testroot');
     await t.hover(testroot.find('li'));

    await t.expect(Selector('.dropdown').visible).ok('dropdown should be visible');
});
```

Comment: It's difficult to say precisely what is the cause of the issue. Could you please create a sample project to reproduce the issue on our side?

Comment: Wasn't that easy, but here you go: https://jsbin.com/bivuzabala
updated question

Comment: Thank you. I reproduced the issue and created a separate ticket in the official testcafe repository: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4493](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4493)